# How can I make Apache return error on wrong http_host?

Tags: apache-2.2

I need to return an error on wrong **http_host** header. For nginx I would write the following config:

```
server { 
    ## Deny illegal Host headers
    if ($host !~* ^(mydomain.com|www.mydomain.com)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }

    location  / {
        proxy_pass               http://app_server;
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I do the same for Apache?

**UPDATE**

Although the trick with virtualhosts does work, I ended up with RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=400]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is an example

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
</VirtualHost>
```

just don't put `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` inside of this `VirtualHost`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved hours of my time. I really have no time to read Apache docs from scratch right now.

Comment: @VladT. you're welcome) i think some things are easier in apache vs nginx.

Comment: This doesn't always fully address the issue. It is better to add DocumentRoot /var/www/catchall and <Directory /var/www/catchall> Order deny,allow Deny from all </Directory>

Answer (score -1):

Just make a `VirtualHost` that matches whatever host header you're interested in and then return whatever error you want.

Comment: Don't you mean VirtualHost?  The NameVirtualHost defines IP/Port on which name based vhosts should be used.  I'd say return the error in the default vhost and only care for vhosts that actually exists :)  But maybe I understand your intention wrong?

Comment: @EEAA Could you please elaborate on your suggestion with simple example? I'm not familiar with Apache config syntax.

Comment: @FrandsHansen you're absolutely right. Corrected. And I agree, just send the error from the default vhost and be done with it.

Comment: @VladT. We don't spoonfeed answers here. Go do a bit of research, this is all very simple stuff. If you can configure nginx, you can surely configure apache.

Comment: @vladT. See here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/    Apache docs are very very good and easy to read/understand :)